# worklight v6.2 console to use LDAP authentication

Tags: ldap, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console

Anyone know how to configure v6.2 to LDAP to authenticate on the console (localhost:10080/worklightconsole/). On v6.1, this is done in authenticationConfig.xml but the migration process to v6.2, automatically removed all the configuration that was configure to use LDAP to secure the console with this comment:
"IBM migration removed customSecurityTest named WorklightConsole. IBM migration removed realm named WorklightConsole. It is not supported as of Worklight v6.2" 
I have already tried following this PDF and still not working - http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/09_11_Using_LDAP_login_module_to_authenticate_user_with_LDAP_server_in_hybrid_applications.pdf
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of Worklight, Worklight Console protection was handled by Worklight's security framework. Starting v6.2, this is now handled by the underlying application server, be it WAS, WAS Liberty profile or Tomcat.

In Worklight Studio WAS Liberty profile is used, so you will need to follow these instructions: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/t_ac_lib_ldap.html?lang=en

For other application servers follow the relevant instructions from here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/c_ac_ldap_jndi.html?lang=en